# Can I load XML response after XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming an XML Response with the XSLT attached in the header with no problem at all. I can access the HTML DOM with Javascript as well. What I want to achieve is to load the original xml **AFTER** the transformation is completed in the browser. Take in account that I am not getting an XML Response from AJAX but as a Page Load. So far what I have done is to replicate the xml dom inside a hidden div during the transformation but I would prefer a more efficient and elegant solution. Thx in advance.

Comment: Do you want to load the XML with Javascript? If window.location.href has the URI any access with XMLHttpRequest (to then use responseXML to have access to the XML  DOM) should take the document from the cache. I am not aware of some browser property, unless you target some very ancient IE versions which I think exposed `document.XMLDocument` and `document.XSLDocument`.

Comment: If you're doing client-side XSLT transformation then yes, there are Javascript APIs that allow you to run the transformation and process the result as a DOM document node. But I'm afraid it's not clear to me exactly what you scenario is.

Comment: Lets say you have a table with all the records in rows after the XSLT transformation and now you want to edit each row showing them in a modal form. Usually people do it with and AJAX call retrieving once again the info from the server or populating the controls in the form with the attributes in the link that opens the modal.
My point is that if you already have that info in the client you should be able to do another transformation with different parameters to populate the form.

Comment: It is not clear whether you run the first transformation with Javascript and XSLTProcessor. If you do that then a second run, only after changing the relevant arguments (using clearParameters and setParameter as needed), and perhaps using the returned document fragment to populate the "modal dialog", should suffice.

Comment: First transformation is adding the link of the transformation in the XML file(which is not a file), the second sould load that xml and uses Js and XsltProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution had to come from the server, instead of using a XML as response now I save the XML Document as a file, with the link to the XSLT, and then redirect to this new xml file. This way I can retrieve the xml from the window.location.href as suggested by [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen)

Then I can load the xml to process with JS and XSLTProcessor to produce the new content on the client. No jQuery or Framewoek needed.

PS. I also change the history URI in case the user needs to refresh the content